# Cast Wrapper-Class to original class

Tags: casting, objective-c++, pimpl-idiom

I use Wrapper-Class using pimpl so I can use Objective-C methods while using C++.

Now in my ViewWrapper.hpp I have this:

```
class ViewWrapper
{
    public:
        void addSubview(ViewWrapper *view); //method exists in original View.h (Objective-C)
        ViewWrapper (void);
        ~ViewWrapper (void);
    private:
        struct Impl;
        Impl* impl;
};
```

In my ViewWrapper.mm:

```
//ViewWrapper.mm

#import "ViewWrapper.hpp"
#import "View.h" // original Objective-C header

struct ViewWrapper::Impl
{
    View* obj;
};

ViewWrapper::ViewWrapper() : impl(new Impl)
{
    impl->obj = [[View alloc] init];
}

void ViewWrapper::addSubview(ViewWrapper *view)
{
    [impl->obj addSubview:(View *) view]; // <- here is the error
}
```

Now in my main.cpp I use it like this:

```
// main.cpp

ViewWrapper *wrapper1 = new ViewWrapper();
ViewWrapper *wrapper2 = new ViewWrapper();
wrapper1->addSubview(wrapper2);
```

Now when I try to compile it, I get the error message

> "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x105)" in my ViewWrapper.mm

I guess my problem is that this is not the correct way of casting ViewWrapper to View. Any other method works just fine (e.g. const char* to NSString and so on..)

Can anyone help me? If you need more info, I'll try to add it as good as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. If anyone faces the same problem, I changed my addSubview-method like that:

`[impl->obj addSubview:(UIView *) view->impl->obj];`